# Use ASP button to call a VB method AND THEN call a Javascript Function 'On Click'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Here is my scenario:

I have an VB ASP "NextPageButton," VB "NextPageButton" on click method, and Javascript "#Next" function shown below. On click, this ASP "NextPageButton" will call the "NextPageButton" method that  displays a msgbox that will ask the user, "Would you like to save before continuing to the next page?" (This is done when the goToRequestedPage() is called within this method). Then, after the user responds, the user should be be able to go to the next page of the BR (BookReader) by way of the Javascript "Next" function shown below. However, I can only get the ASP "NextPageButton" to call its VB "NextPageButton" method, but not the Javascript "#Next" function.

// Here is the VB ASP "NextPageButton":

```
<asp:Button ID="NextPageButton" runat="server" Text="Next Page" Height="24px" />
```

// Here is the "NextPageButton" VB method that is called when the ASP "NextPageButton" is // clicked

```
Protected Sub NextPageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextPageButton.Click
        Dim TransAdapter As New TransTableAdapter
        ' Increment global current page number by one page
        gbCurrentPage += 1
        'autoSaveCheckBoxStatus()
        goToRequestedPage()
End Sub
```

---

//Here is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function () {
```

// Specifically, here is the Javascript "Next" Function that I want to be called "on                          //click," after the "NextPageButton" method is completed, described above: (This calls the //RenderBR() Function)

```
 $("#Next").click(function () {
                if (splitType == "v") {
                    RenderBR('#CenterLeft', gbCurrentPage + 1);
                }
                else {
                    RenderBR('#CenterTop', gbCurrentPage + 1);
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

***** Question: How can I get the ASP "NextPageButton" to call the VB "NextPageButton" Method AND THEN call the Javascript "#Next" Function after user answers MsgBox question???

Comment: You will not be able to call the JavaScript function, as you have it written, from the server-side code, because you have an anonymous function as your callback from the jQuery selector `$("#Next").click()`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't.
When you do a postback in Webforms you have lost the client. Say it did work - should the javascript run on the page that is about to close or magically appear on the upcoming page?

Read up on the event order in Aspnet
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx
http://hemantg.blogspot.se/2010/12/aspnet-event-sequence.html
and rethink.

Unfortunately I cannot give you a better answer than that.

Comment: Okay, do you have any good alternative solutions to get around this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Not without knowing lots more about your real underlying problem an that is out of scope for Stackoverflow.   Rethink, redesign and make sure you aren't having a X-Y-problem(http://www.selfelected.com/the-x-y-problem/)

Comment: Thanks, I have redesigned my program, and have posted a question titled, "How to use Public Shared Sub to call functionality found in a Protected Sub goToRequestedPage() in Visual Basic"

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken the `NextPageButton` will call the `NextPageButton_Click` function when you click it, so you just need to call the Javascript one after the user clicks the button. To do this, I recommend the following changes:

Create a function that will be called from your button client click, as well as from the server side:

```
function functionCall()
{
    if (splitType == "v") 
    {
        RenderBR('#CenterLeft', gbCurrentPage + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        RenderBR('#CenterTop', gbCurrentPage + 1);
    }
}
```

This calls it from your button click:

```
$("#Next").click(function () 
{
    functionCall();
});
```

Now we call it from the server after your click event is executed:

```
Protected Sub NextPageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextPageButton.Click
        Dim TransAdapter As New TransTableAdapter
        ' Increment global current page number by one page
        gbCurrentPage += 1
        'autoSaveCheckBoxStatus()
        goToRequestedPage()
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "functionCall", "functionCall();", true);
End Sub
```

This, however, will be executed after the `PostBack` has occured. If the `goToRequestedPage()` method does a redirect, this javascript code will not be executed.